# How to create random numbers in a cell array with some probability

Tags: matlab

I wanted to create a set of random numbers. I used the following code:

```
for i = 1:n
 for j = 1:n
   Sc{i,j} = sort((randperm(m,randi(m)))); 
end;
end;
```

This creates a cell array containing a set of random integers from 1 to 5. example Sc{1,1} = [1,3,4] I think, randi function uses uniform distribution. I want to control size of the set with some probabilty. For example I want my set to contain all 5 elements (that is of size 5) with a probability of .5 and and a set with 4, 3, 2,1 elements with probability .1 each. I don't know how to code it in matlab. Please help. I am fairly new to this software

Comment: Your description is strange. In any way I could sum up the probabilities, I don't end with 1.

Comment: do you know how to code it in a different language? to me this doesn't seem like a "matlab" question, but rather concerning the algorithm/method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick. Basically what you need to do, since there is really no straight fotward way of defining a custom weighted distribution, you can simply create an array that has the higher weighted elements in it more often, and then uniformly sample that array. So if some element has a probability of 0.5 then half the elements in your created array will be that value with probability of 0.5. Then, as said, simply use `randi` (with the whole array length) to select an index from that array, which will follow your custom distribution.

See code below

```
sizes = [1,2,3,4,5];
probs = [0.125,0.125,0.125,0.125,0.5];

% some initial sanity checks.
assert(numel(sizes) == numel(probs),'probability must be defined for each size')
assert(sum(probs)==1,'Probabilities must sum to 1')

numEach = round((probs/min(probs)));
weightedSizes = zeros(1,sum(numEach));    

start = 1;
for i = 1:numel(sizes)
    weightedSizes(start:start+numEach(i)-1) = sizes(i);
    start = start+numEach(i);
end

holder = cell(1,10);
for i = 1:10
    randSize = weightedSizes(randi(numel(weightedSizes)));
    holder{i} = randperm(randSize);
end
```

Note, be very careful using this method if you have something with a very small probability as it will create a very large matrix. This is because it assumes that the element with the smallest probability only appears once. There will be as many elements as `1/min(probability)`

Comment: while my solution does work, I would actually suggest using the solution in the question this is duplicating. The one that Eitan T provided as it is much simpler, does not have the same limitations mine does, and run a lot faster.